# removing spaces in string in javascript

Tags: javascript

hello all i want to tranform my string with to much spaces to a more readable  structure so i want to remove all the beginning spaces. 
Its an output from a pdf extracter and the text is all over the place i tried already .replace(/\s+/g, " ") but this will also remove all my white lines and i save this output to a txt file so that not nice because you have to scroll a lot in this way

i need this :
BARCODE INFO

Barcode Type EAN 13
 Magniﬁcation:

BWR Applied: 80%

Full Height 10 microns

Bar Height:

Rotation Applied: 16.8 mm

13.5 mm
 ??º

Mechanical Artwork

**from this**

```
                                                                                                                                                                                    BARCODE INFO

                                                                                                                                                                                    Barcode Type                                                                                                                  EAN 13
                                                                                                                                                                                    Magniﬁcation:
                                                                                                                                                                                    BWR Applied:                                                                                                                  80%
                                                                                                                                                                                    Full Height                                                                                                                   10 microns
                                                                                                                                                                                    Bar Height:
                                                                                                                                                                                    Rotation Applied:                                                                                                             16.8 mm
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  13.5 mm
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ??º

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Mechanical Artwork
```

Comment: Since `\s` also matches tabs and linebreaks, just use `/ +/g` instead. (That's a space character in there). (also kinda meta funny that this question is talking about making something "more readable")

Comment: thanks this worked i need to study regex more

Answer (score 0):

you can use trim() method to remove any space at the begining.

Answer (score 0):

```
.replace(/\s+/, "")
```

It will replace the first whitespace only, this includes spaces, tabs and new lines.

To replace all whitespace in the string you need to use global mode

```
.replace(/\s/g, "")
```